# Scala - Overriding a Java interface method in a Scala class

Tags: java, scala

I have a Java interface **Writer** defined as following:

```
public interface Writer<K, V> {

    Iterator<Product2<K, V>> iterator ();
}
```

And i am trying to implement this interface in a Scala class **ExternalWriter** which is as following:

```
private class ExternalWriter[K, V, C]
  extends Logging
  with Writer[K, V] {

    override def iterator(): Iterator[Product2[K, C]] = {
        partitionedIterator.flatMap(pair => pair._2)
  }
}
```

But when I try to compile this code, I get an error:

> Error: Overriding method iterator in trait SortShuffleFileWriter of
>   type ()Iterator[Product2[K,V]];  method iterator has incompatible type
>   override def iterator(): Iterator[Product2[K, C]] = {

How do I fix this?

Comment: The `java.util.Iterator` interface is separate from the `scala.collection.Iterator` trait (in addition to the problem @Codebender mentioned). Did you account for that?

Answer (score 2):

Why did you change `V` to `C`?

Your override method should be,

```
override def iterator(): Iterator[Product2[K, V]] = {
    partitionedIterator.flatMap(pair => pair._2)
```

If you want to use `C`, then you should implement `Writer` with `C` as,

```
with Writer[K, C] {
```

Comment: When I change the override method to override def iterator(): Iterator[Product2[K, V]] I get the following error

Error: type mismatch;
 found   : Iterator[Product2[K,C]]
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[Product2[K,V]]
    partitionedIterator.flatMap(pair => pair._2)
                                             ^

Comment: @HaseebJaved, did you try to change your `with` instead as I have mentioned.

Comment: yes but that lead to all sorts of other errors like:
Error:(90, 22) class ExternalWriter needs to be abstract, since method insertAll in trait Writer of type (x$1: Iterator[Product2[K,C]])Unit is not defined
(Note that Iterator[Product2[K,C]] does not match Iterator[Product2[K,V]]: their type parameters differ)
private[spark] class ExternalWriter[K, V, C](

I guess I have the structure of my program all wrong and may be I should start anew.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing Iterator in your scala class with java.util.Iterator as the scala Iterator and the java Iterator are different.

```
private class ExternalWriter[K, V, C]
  extends Logging
  with Writer[K, V] {

    override def iterator(): java.util.Iterator[Product2[K, C]] = {
        partitionedIterator.flatMap(pair => pair._2)
  }
}
```

The above would be the modified code.